# The integral of an exact form over an orientable closed manifold is $0$

Tags: differential-forms

A form $\beta^{p}$ is closed if $d\beta=0$.

A form $\beta^{p}$ is exact if $\beta^{p}=d\alpha^{p-1}$, for some form $\alpha^{p-1}$.

---

An orientable closed manifold is a compact manifold without boundary.

---

What is a compact manifold?

Why is an orientable closed manifold the same as a compact manifold without boundary?

If a manifold is compact, does it not, be definition, have a boundary?

---

How do you prove that the integral of an exact form over an orientable closed manifold is $0$?

Comment: Voting to close as "missing context": If you don't know what a compact manifold (such as a circle, a sphere, a torus...) is, explaining integration of forms is the subject of a short course or textbook, not a Math.SE post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will try to answer your questions:

1) A manifold is compact if every open covering (i.e. a collection of open sets that contains the manifold in its union) has a finite subcovering. So from this open covering, which might have infinitely many sets, you can choose finitely many and these must still cover the manifold.

2)On this website https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_manifolds a closed manifold is defined as a compact manifold without boundary.

3) No, a compact manifold could have no boundary. For example, consider the circle $S^1$. It is definitely compact and does not have a boundary.

4) As we have just concluded that this manifold has no boundary, we can just use Stoke's theorem for our manifold $M$:
\begin{equation}
\int_{M} d\omega = \int_{\partial M} \omega.
\end{equation}
We have an exact form, let's call it $\beta^p$. As you already said, this means that $\beta^p=d\alpha^{p-1}$. Also, because $M$ has no boundary, the integral over $\partial M$ will be zero:
\begin{equation}
\int_M \beta^p = \int_M d\alpha^{p-1} = \int_{\partial M} \alpha^{p-1} =0.
\end{equation}

Comment: What is an example of a compact manifold with boundary?

Comment: Just an interval for example: [-1,1]